# Enumerate subclassed array in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, prototype

I want a reusable list with my own custom behaviors (e.g. `updateOrAppendByItemId`) to hold a retrieved array for enumeration via `ngRepeat`. The main purpose is to hold live collections - contents might be changed locally or remotely (via SignalR). It should:

- enumerate properly in an `ng-repeat` directive
- not render my custom behaviors as items (rows)
- retain sort order from de-serialized source
- behave across modern browsers
- avoid unnecessary list copying

How should it generally be constructed?

---

I've immediately run into conceptual problems when building it a few different ways. A JavaScript `Array` can't be subclassed. Copying my behavioral prototype directly to an `Array` instance results in undesired enumerable properties. Storing contents in object properties loses source item order.

Each of those problems currently has only theoretical severity to me, with real-world consequences that depend on both undocumented AngularJS behavior and browser differences. I'm hoping someone who has touched this problem before can save me lots of trial-and-error.

---

**Research:**

Since I'm starting that potentially lengthy investigation I was hoping to avoid, I'll post my work here.

Angular's `ngRepeat` first tests if a collection `isArrayLike()`. If it is, it simply iterates through the length of the collection numerically. That seems highly intentional (although I wouldn't want to depend on the interpretation of the internal function `isArrayLike()`).

In the one browser I tested in so far, neither of the following change the effective array contents.

```
// safe
array.myMethod = true;
array['myMethod'] = true;
```

However, the following is disastrous: /grin

```
array['5'] = true;
```

So, that's [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4):

> A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if
>   and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not
>   equal to 232−1.

I may not have to go any further. I'll try this solution and report back.

Comment: I think you could write your own ng-repeat directive that fits your unique needs. Or, maybe a filter could do the job of filtering out unnecessary object properties and only return "pure" data suitable for ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank you Huy. Those both seem like reasonable fallback plans if I can't get a basic object to behave dependably.